# Need to extract the top values from a scatter (x-y) plot: highest X and highest Y

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, scatter-plot

I have a dataset with different values as follow:

```
     name   X   Y
       a    1   8
       b    11  12
       c    8   8
       d    4   13
       e    12  4
       f    11  11
       g    0   8
       h    0   9
       i    11  7
```

And a plot based on it:

[image]

What I need to get is a dataframe with the top 4 (in red circle) or top 'any number'. Something similar like this:

```
  name  X   Y
    b   11  12
    f   11  11
    i   11  7
    c   8   8
```

I've been using the following but it doesn't work well:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['A', 'B'],ascending=False)
print(df1)
```

Comment: write your custom function for comparing  and pass it to sort . `soionrt(.., key=customFunction)`

Comment: sorry, a clarification... instead of giving a specific range, I need the script to automatically find the twenty values that have the highest values on both axis. @AnkurJyotiPhukan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following:

```
 df['Z']= (df.X*df.Y)
 df2=(df.sort_values('Z',ascending=False).head(4))
 df2[['X','Y']]
```

output:

```
 X  Y
11  12
11  11
11  7
8   8
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand what's your really mean of 'highest'. The points in the red circle are not all top 4 points in X or Y axis.

SO I think what you mean may be the distance between  specified points and a reference point ( e.g. [0,0] or something else). 
if that's the case, may try to define a new paramter.

df['c']=np.sqrt((df['x']-X0)**2+(df['y']-Y0)**2)

df=df.sorted_value(['c'],ascending=False)